# Is "vest" the root of "invest"?

Tags: morphology, derivational-morphology

From [this link](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=invest) it's somewhat likely that "invest" can be broken down to "in"+"vest". But does that make sense? In that case, which type of derivational morpheme is "in-"? I only know of it as a prefix that change adj into an opposite adj... What do you call this type of "in-" that goes with verbs (if it actually exists grammatically)?

Comment: The same [site](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=in-) will give you the answer about the prefix _**in-**_. See entry 2.

Comment: There are two prefixes _in-_. The one you are thinking of is a negative, right enough. But the other one just means "going into" something, and that's the one in _invest_. You put money in when you invest; when you take your money out, it's called _divesting_; different set of prefixes. These were all borrowed from Latin with the prefixes already installed and then they were banged around with English words for centuries, so they don't make a lot of sense any more. That's why so many things in English have to be memorized in lists -- the rules are in flux.

Comment: Don't you think 'invest' is almost a literal translation of 'dress in'?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin That's what I thought too. Now, from 'dressing in' to 'putting money in' is a big leap. And I don't even understand what 'dress in' is.

Comment: @longtry If that seems like a big leap consider, for instance, how  'dressing in' might be seen as 'wrapping yourself in' and 'putting money in' might be said to be 'wrapping your money in(to)'

Let's remember, whether any of this comes from Latin or German, it came when? 1,000 years ago, at least and so has had plenty of time to settle itself in.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Ah, I can see that if we think of Middle Ages folks as people who worship money / regard it very highly / consider it the same as themselves then the word transformation will make sense. We do have a lot of such folks in society nowadays, so the leap may be shorter than first seemed.

Comment: @longtry That might be true and I'm sorry to say, I don't think it's relevant. What did you find when you asked your own search engines about the etymology of 'invest', as for instance at https://www.google.com/search?q=invest+etymology&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB779GB779&oq=invest+etymology&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i15i22i30j0i22i30l2j0i15i22i30j0i390l3.5138j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8?

Comment: @longtry If 'dress in' makes no sense, try for instance 'I dress in black…' or 'you dress in suits…'. Try 'she dresses in whatever feels good today…' or 'they dress in clothes that seem appropriate…' or even, for instance, 'I/you/he/she/they dress in style'.